# An integer [0,4095] 12bits to a tuble{A,B,C} the fastest way in c++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, bit-manipulation

Intput: An integer [0,4095] 12bits.
Output: A tuble of {A,B,C} all [0,255]

The A,B,C are given as 0 to 255, where 255 maps to 15 in the 4 bits. Reason are that I want to construct a Color struct having RGB defined from 0 to 255.

I assume the solution to be something like bit shifting the input to extract the 3 sets of 4bits and then multiply by 17 as  (255/15 | 15 = 1111(binary)).

How would you compute this fastest?

my own solution:

```
QColor mycolor(int value)
{
if(value > 0xFFF)
    value = 0xFFF;

int a=0,b=0,c=0;
a = (value & 0xF) * 17;
b = ((value&(0xF<<4))>>4) *17;
c = ((value&(0xF<<8))>>8) *17;
return QColor(c,b,a);
}



cv::Mat cv_image(10,10,CV_16U,cv::Scalar::all(1));
QImage image(cv_image.data, 10,10,QImage::Format_RGB444);
QPainter p(&image);
p.setPen(mycolor(255));
p.drawLine(0,0,9,0);
p.setPen(mycolor(4095));
p.drawLine(0,1,9,1);
p.setPen(mycolor(0));
p.drawLine(0,2,9,2);
p.setPen(mycolor(10000));
p.drawLine(0,3,9,3);


********* Start testing of Test1 *********
Config: Using QTest library 4.7.4, Qt 4.7.4
PASS   : Test1::initTestCase()
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095, 4095;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
PASS   : Test1::test1()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all input 0...4096 is in fact 12 bits and this makes the question easier to understand. Here is one possible solution:

```
int val; // 0...4096
int red =   ((val&(255<<8))>>8)*17;
int green = ((val&(255<<4))>>4)*17;
int blue =  ((val&(255<<0))>>0)*17;
```

I have kept the bit shifting for blue as well so you can spot the similarity in the calculation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Testing if it works :) looks fine. Have to figure out why both shifting right and left though. Just added what i came up with myself, havent testet it yet

Comment: you need to bit shift right as well because you calculate val&111100000000 so the result obtained will be <red>00000000 which has 12 zeros after the red value.

Comment: Yes,sorry. It should be either 0xf  or 15.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first four bits from the input, you can `AND` it with `1111`, then bitshift the input to the right by four bits and repeat the process. This gets you three integers in the range of 0 to 15.

If you then want to convert that to something in [0,255], then bitshift everything to the left by four bits and `OR` it with `1111` (for simplicity).

```
A = (input&15)<<4|15;
input >>= 4;
B = (input&15)<<4|15;
input >>= 4;
C = (input&15)<<4|15;
```

or (if you want 0 to map to 0)

```
A = input&15;
A = A<<4|A;
input >>= 4;
B = input&15;
B = B<<4|B;
input >>= 4;
C = input&15;
C = C<<4|C;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unions to better parse your color coded 12 bit value.

```
union colorCoding
{
  unsigned int val:12;
  struct
  {
    unsigned int red:4;
    unsigned int blue:4;
    unsigned int green:4;
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Though my colour implementation is QColor from Qt. Im just working on a opencv Mat Qimage conversion for the CV_16U and qt format RGB444 .

Comment: While I don't know how well it works in this case, in general, unions should not be used this way. Structs can add arbitrary padding between member variables, leading to undefined behaviour.